# Wrap a partial pattern matching into a Maybe

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, option-type

Is there any way to wrap a partial pattern-match into a Maybe?

I wish to write some code kind of like this:

```hs
fromMaybe defaultValue $ do
  [a, b] <- mkList :: [Int]
  [x] <- mkList' a b :: [Int]
  return $ x
```

where this expression's value would be `defaultValue` if `mkList` evaluates to a list with length /= 2, or if `mkList' a b` evaluates to a list of length /= 1. Otherwise the expression evaluates to the only element returned by `mkList' a b`.

I figured the `Maybe` monad would be great to achieve this. But how can I turn a failed pattern-matching into a `Nothing`, and a successful match into a `Just`?

Is it possible to achieve this in Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost works as is. You only need to add some `pure` and change the type:

```
import Data.Maybe

f defaultValue mkList mkList' = fromMaybe defaultValue $ do
  [a, b] <- pure mkList :: Maybe [Int]
  [x] <- pure (mkList' a b) :: Maybe [Int]
  return x
```

You don't even need those `:: Maybe [Int]` annotations.

In GHCi you can see it has the expected behavior:

```
ghci> f 0 [1,2,3] (\x y -> [x,y])
0
ghci> f 0 [1,2] (\x y -> [x])
1
ghci> f 0 [1,2] (\x y -> [y])
2
ghci> f 0 [1,2] (\x y -> [x,y])
0
```

The mechanism behind it is explained by Daniel Wagner in the comments:

> ```
> do
>  [a, b] <- <X>
>  <Y>
> ```
>
> is syntax sugar for
>
> ```
> let ok [a, b] = do <Y>
>     ok _ = fail "..."
> in <X> >>= ok
> ```
>
> (And for Maybe, the definition of fail is `fail _ = Nothing`.)
>
> See [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14).

Note that this only works inside `do` blocks where the monad is an instance of `MonadFail`.

Comment: Wait... HOW does that work? How does `Maybe`'s `>>=` bail out, if pattern matching against a `Just [1,2,3]` fails?

Comment: `(Just [1,2,3] :: Maybe [Int]) >>= (\[a,b] -> ())` fails... Isn't `[a, b] <- pure mkList :: Maybe [Int]` supposed to be syntax sugar for that?

Comment: yes, but `MonadFail` comes in in these cases, where the monad implements that class (as `Maybe` does). If there's no instance using such a "failable" pattern would be a compilation error I believe. See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fail.html

Comment: @BlueNebula No, `[a, b] <- <X>; <Y>` is syntax sugar for `let ok [a, b] = <Y>; ok _ = fail <Z> in <X> >>= ok`. (And for `Maybe`, the definition of `fail` is `fail _ = Nothing`.) See [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14).

Comment: Thanks guys! Now it's clear to me how this works.